# Auto activate outline on button when form is open

Tags: html, jquery

[This image shown the modal when it's open, and I would like to make either my offline or online button have an outline as shown in image 2 according to the current status.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Isyhq.png)

[I want this kind of outline but not just when click on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhAAq.png)

I have tried to use focus but nothing happen so I'm not sure if there are any jquery or html method to help with this? I'm still kind of new to the language

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit Context</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
         <div class="form-group col-md-4 justify-content-center">
                <label>Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="Name" name="codename" class="form-control" disabled value="">
              </div>  
              <div class="form-group col-md-4 ">
                <label> Display Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="DN" name="displayname" class="form-control">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                <label>Status</label>  

                <input type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success d-block mx-auto my-3 " id="Geton"  value="Online"   >
                
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger d-block mx-auto my-3" id="Getoff" value = "Offline"  >


               
              </div>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" id="Save" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is my html part for the modal I'm using , as for style I'm using bootstrap classes.

currently I'm trying to add css according to value I got when page is load as show in code below anyone got a better ideas?

```
if(stat == 'online'){
        alert(stat)
        createModal.find("#Geton").css("outline", "3px solid")

    }
```

Comment: Please include an example of the markup + styles you are trying to modify (in the question, as text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add this effect you shouldn't use border or outline.
Just use box-shadow.
(this box-shadow is from bootstrap.)

```css
button
{
  background-color : #fff;
  padding : 10px;
  border-radius : 10px;
  color : #198754;
  border : 1px solid #198754;
  transition : 0.2s ease;
  cursor:pointer;
  box-shadow : 0 0 0 0.25rem rgba(25,135,84,0.5);
}
button:focus
{
    color : #fff;
    background-color : #198754;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button>Online</button>
</body>
</html>
```